# one to many relationship in .net mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

View Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
    {
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string phone { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string email { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Employee</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

         <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
             </div>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
 </div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I want to take multiple Phone numbers and email addresses from view at the same time if user wants to insert more than one.

till works fine but how to implement for phone number and email address??

Thanks.

Comment: as a `List` or other `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Plz can you explain with some code.
i am new to .net.

Thank you
and how to handle in view

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to break out phone and email as their own classes and then add a one-to-many relationship between them and `Employee`:

```
public class Phone
{
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public class Email
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir ..

but please can you help me to generate view i.e. i suppose want to take 3 Emails so how can i create my view, Please